# How to make names and descriptions clickable hyperlinks in addition to page numbers in a glossary?

Tags: glossaries, hyperlink, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

By default, in a glossary only the page numbers are clickable hyperlinks.

- ***Q:*** How could one also make the names and descriptions of entries into clickable hyperlinks?

This would be analogous to hyperref's `linktoc=all` option for table of  contents, thus yielding a uniform appearence for the PDF document.

I am using `glossaries-extra` package with the intermediate step of `bib2gls`. The separate `.bib`-file is named `testentries.bib` for the MWE.

> We may assume that each glossary entry has exactly one page number link. This is precisely my use-case.
> [In response to [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah)'s thoughtful [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690386/how-to-make-names-and-descriptions-clickable-hyperlinks-in-addition-to-page-numb?noredirect=1#comment1713252_690386).]

In my document, I only use `\gls*`. And for each entry in the `.bib`-file, `\gls*{entry}` is used exactly one time in the main document. This is because the references are essentially to the first introduction of important terms in a mathematical text and there can be only one ‘first introduction’.

*(If you find this assumption too restrictive, you may solve a more general case, taking for instance the "first" page number's link, or the link of another page number, somehow designated as "main" reference for that entry. However,* there is no need *for such generality sporting for my usage :)).*

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft} % for creating dots as in table of contents
\usepackage{titlesec} % might change something, not sure
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} % importing hyperref with blue-colored links
\usepackage[record, stylemods={default}, style={alttree}]{glossaries-extra} % importing glossaries-extra alttree style and record option

\GlsXtrLoadResources[src={testentries}, break-at={none},type={main}] % creating the glossary based on testentries.bib via bib2gls
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{textbf} % adding textbf formatting to glossary entry names

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}} % same dots in table of contents and glossary
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}} % same dots in table of contents and glossary

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Test Chapter}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    \gls{TestEntry1} bla bla
    \lipsum[2-6]
    \gls*{TestEntry2} bla bla bla
    
    \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\currentglossary]} % nice formatting of names and descriptions (inc. no overlaps)
    \printunsrtglossary[type=main] % prints glossary

\end{document}
```

The `.bib`-file `testentries.bib`:

```
@entry{TestEntry1,
name={TestEntry1},
text={Name of TestEntry1},
description={Some made-up description of TestEntry1}
}

@entry{TestEntry2,
name={TestEntry2, Longer},
text={Name of TestEntry2},
description={Some made-up description of TestEntry2}
}
```

Output of glossary (as one notices, the blue hyperlinks are restricted to simply the page numbers at the end of the lines)

[image: Output of glossary]

Comment: In opposite to the table of contents, glossary entries usually do not have only one reference, e.g. if you would add one more `\gls{TestEntry1}` at the second page. This would add one more page reference with link. But how should it add one more link to the name and description?

Comment: @cabohah Your point is well taken. In my use case, there is exactly one page number per entry. (We can imagine that if there were several, the "first" link should be taken, or another link somehow designated as "main". However, that's another question. So let's assume there is exactly one page reference per entry, which is also exactly what I need).